# vim not reading Tab key as <Tab>

Tags: vim

I am using vim 7 on Kubuntu. I have just installed the UltiSnips plugin and I noticed that the Tab key was not expanding the snippets. After checking the mapping of the key and verifying it was correct, I found that when I hit Tab, my vim (and gvim) read it as `^GS`, not as `<Tab>`.

I found that `^GS` was a mapping from the surround plugin and after removing it, the Tab key is read as `^H` but it still doesn't trigger the snippet, and there is no mapping for `^H`.

How can I get the Tab key to be read as `<Tab>`?

Answer (score 0):

Upon more investigation, this is not related to vim and the way it handles `<Tab>`. It was a problem in UltiSnips and custom snippets not been read.